# Need VB code that will merge two sheets into a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VB, and need some help. I have an excel 2013 workbook that has 2 sheets. Sheet1 is list of employee names (column A has 20 names), dob (column B), etc, and Sheet2 is a blank evaluation form. I need a code that will copy the entire Sheet2 (the blank form) and paste into a new Sheet3, and also pull the EmpName from row1 to a specified cell on Sheet3 (D4), same with DOB (J4), etc.  I need it to repeat this process for every name on Sheet1.  End goal is to have a workbook that contains 20 sheets, one for each employee, in the form of an evaluation. It would also be terrific if this code could name the tab the employee name.  Is this possible?  I've searched online extensively, and cannot find anything fitting.

Here is my current code. Like I said, I'm a VBA newbie. The code creates new sheets from the employee list, and copies data, but now I need it to also copy the entire sheet2 (eval form), and place the data (name cell A1 from employee list) into the form on sheet3 (new sheet) in cell D4.

Sub CreateSheetsFromEmployeeList()

```
Dim nameSource  
Dim nameColumn      
Dim nameStartRow    As Long     
Dim nameEndRow      As Long     
Dim employeeName    As String   
Dim newSheet        As Worksheet    

nameSource = "Ayre" 
nameColumn = "A"    
nameStartRow = 2    

nameEndRow = Worksheets(nameSource).Cells(Rows.Count, nameColumn).End(xlUp).Row 
Do While (nameStartRow <= nameEndRow)   
    employeeName = Sheets(nameSource).Cells(nameStartRow, nameColumn)   
    employeeName = Trim(employeeName)   
    If (employeeName <> vbNullString) Then  
        On Error Resume Next 'do not throw error    
        Err.Clear 'clear any existing error 

        Sheets(employeeName).Name = employeeName    
        If (Err.Number > 0) Then    
            Err.Clear   
            On Error GoTo -1    
            Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))  
            newSheet.Name = employeeName    

            Sheets(nameSource).Activate 
            LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(nameStartRow, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   
            Range(Cells(nameStartRow, 1), Cells(nameStartRow, LastCol)).Select  
            Selection.Copy  

            Sheets(employeeName).Activate  'NEW 
            Sheets(employeeName).Cells(1, "A").PasteSpecial 
            [a1].Select  'NEW   
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 
            Sheets(employeeName).Columns("A:K").AutoFit 
        End If  
    End If  
    nameStartRow = nameStartRow + 1     
Loop    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you offer the code to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Here is my current code.  Like I said, I'm a VBA newbie.  The code creates new sheets from the employee list, and copies data, but now I need it to also copy the entire sheet2 (eval form), and place the data (name cell A1 from employee list) into the form on sheet3 (new sheet) in cell D4.

Answer (score 0):

## [Record a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-2841ba85-9da6-4bd7-93a4-0da90844f283?CorrelationId=633ccce5-21a8-4af4-be9e-ee7eac8683e2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP010342374)

When you record a macro, the macro recorder records all the steps required to complete the actions that you want your macro to perform.  Iterate your action once, stop recording, then view the macro to repeat and build out your final automation macro.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates the basic principles you need:

```
Sub ExampleForAngel()
    Dim names As Worksheet
    Set names = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim eval As Worksheet
    Set eval = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim index As Long
    index = 0
    Dim name As String
    While (names.Range("A1").Offset(index, 0).Value <> "")
        name = names.Range("A1").Offset(index, 0)
        eval.Copy after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.name = name
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = name
        index = index + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!  I added the code below to copy specific info from Sheet1 to the new sheet, but it of course pulls the data from row1 repeatedly. What do I add to have it pull the data from the next row?       Range("F4:G4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet1!R[-2]C[-3]"

Comment: My goal was just to point you in the right direction, angel. Think of the satisfaction you will feel when you work out the details on your own. Good luck.